# CKEditor5 Plugin with angular

Tags: angular, webpack, ckeditor5

I am using the CKEditor5 custom build for angular (13) and I am trying to implement their example "Placeholder" plugin. When I try to run my app, I get the below error. I assume I'll need to add something to my angular.json...but I'm not sure what.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/three-vertical-dots.svg 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="9.5" cy="4.5" r="1.5"/><circle cx="9.5" cy="10.5" r="1.5"/><circle cx="9.5" cy="16.5" r="1.5"/></svg>
```

Here is the relevent lines from my component.ts file:

```
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CKEditorUploadAdapter } from 'src/app/_helpers/ckeditor-upload-adapter';
import { ConferenceViewModelWithDetails, PaperAcknowledgementViewModel, PaperConfigurationViewModel } from 'src/app/_models/generatedModels';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/_services/authentication.service';
import { AdminCallForPapersService, OrganizationService } from 'src/app/_services/generatedServices';
import { ToasterService } from 'src/app/_services/toaster.service';
import * as customBuild from 'src/ckCustomBuild/ckeditor';
import * as Placeholder from 'src/ckCustomBuild/placeholder.plugin';


@Component({
  selector: 'bxl-abstract-management-configuration',
  templateUrl: 'abstract-management-configuration.component.html',
})
export class AbstractManagementConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {
  initialized = false;
  public Editor = customBuild;

  htmlEditorConfig = {
    plugins: [Placeholder],
    toolbar: {
      items: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', 'alignment', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|', 'Paceholder'],
      shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false,
    },
    placeholderConfig: {
      types: ['date', 'color', 'first name', 'surname'],
    },
    fontSize: {
      options: [9, 11, 13, 'default', 17, 19, 21],
    },
    mediaEmbed: {
      previewsInData: true,
    },
  };
```

They say to put this in the `webpack.config.json` but we don't have that on angular 13.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
            use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
        },
```